Error The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token
I get the token this way
$serviceAccountFile = '/var/www/html/credentials.json';
    $scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'];

    $credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials(
        $scopes,
        $serviceAccountFile
    );

    $token = $credentials->fetchAuthToken();
    $accessToken = $token['access_token'];

Then I send the received token for testing with Postman
In header Authorization: Bearer token - received token
Body:
{"message": {
"token": "eVkcH93BTwmpd06HPtuxeY:APA91bHNW6ZIAOe1IOKmpdHmiRQSnN69X_s4Duq0bYbaCt6IVDsh80KkjBNRxVoUMRUyRoHjn6HQlRrm9I5_Kj0eciorJ9rrlfUqeDJwiBcrFpV5aZeNwsRmOXPIkPeZJeHHQdKSM_ERs",
"notification": {
  "title": "Breaking News",
  "body": "New news story available."
},
"data": {
  "story_id": "story_12345"
}}}

And answer from server
{
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
            "errorCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
        }
    ]
}}

What could be the reason for this?

Doesn't the access token go in the header when you're sending a message? That's more normal. The token isn't really a part of the message itself. Check the documentation
